# How to use jq for a query where key is a numeric string

Tags: syntax, jq, invocation

Recently discovered `jq` and am using it to format some data.

How do I use it to access fields of a json object that happen to be numeric strings?

For example, the following fails for me with an error:

`echo '{"20":"twenty"}' | jq .["20"]`

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Purely a shell problem, not a jq problem. The shell isn't passing the quotes to jq at all, because it's parsing them as syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Immediate Answer: Use More Quotes

In `jq .["20"]`, the double quotes are parsed as shell syntax, not `jq` syntax (shell quoting is character-by-character: One can switch quoting types within a larger string). Use single quotes to protect that entire string from modification by the shell:

```
$ echo '{"20":"twenty"}' | jq '.["20"]'
"twenty"
```

---

#### Finding The Problem Yourself

One approach to diagnosing this kind of problem is using the shell's `xtrace` facility, to tell the shell to echo back to you the command lines it's running:

```
$ set -x
$ echo '{"20":"twenty"}' | jq .["20"]
+ echo '{"20":"twenty"}'
+ jq '.[20]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index object with number
```

As you can see, `jq .["20"]` was parsed as being identical to `jq '.[20]'`

Comment: Other variations in a bash-like environment: `jq '."20"'`, `jq '.[20|tostring]'`, and `jq 'getpath(["20"])'`