# "Invalid numeric literal" error from jq trying to modify JSON with variable

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am wanting to pipe values into a bash script that will change values in a json file using jq. I've been working on this for a while now and I can't get past the first set of errors.

Here is my simple json file:

```
{
    "0000000": {
        "pogo": "AJHVUYKJBOIHKNNLNM"
    },
    "7000000": {
        "pogo": "PPPVUYKJBOIHKNNLNM"
    }
}
```

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

#-- pass into script
pgid="${1}"
tpogo="${2}"
file="file.json"

#-- tmp files
tmp_dir="$(mktemp -d -t 'text.XXXXX' || mktemp -d 2>/dev/null)"
tmp_input1="${tmp_dir}/temp_input1.txt"

if [ ! -n "$2" ]; then
   { echo "Check your command as you are missing a variable ..."; echo "Example: script.sh "00000001" "jvkkjbkjbd" ..."; }
   exit 1;
fi

jq -r ".${pgid}.pogo = \"${tpogo}\"" "$file" > "$tmp_input1"
cat "$tmp_input1"
rm -rf "$tmp_dir"
```

Here are the errors:

```
jq: error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 9 (while parsing '.0000000.') at <top-level>, line 1:
.0000000.pogo = "XXXXXXX"
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.0000000.pogo = "XXXXXXX"
jq: 2 compile errors
```

I have tried so many variations from stack and most of them look similar to what I am doing now.

Comment: Parts of this are duplicative of [How to use `jq` for a query where key is a numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460453/how-to-use-jq-for-a-query-where-key-is-a-numeric-string/52460866#52460866).

Comment: @Barmar I did so mate. Surely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the immediate issue: `.key` works with `{ "foo": "value" }`, but `.100` doesn't work with `{ "100": "value" }`; the syntax you're relying is sugar, only available for a limited subset of keys. `.["100"]` would work, but generating that by expanding shell variables into strings parsed as code is fragile (`jq` isn't a side-effecting language as of current releases, but in languages that *do* support I/O operations, such substitutions can be leveraged for injection attacks). To do things the Right Way, pass your variables out-of-band from your code, and use them for lookups in a manner that doesn't rely on what they contain.

---

The `jq` equivalent to awk's `-v var="$value"` is `--arg var "$value"`, used thusly:

```
jq --arg pgid "$pgid" \
   --arg tpogo "$tpogo" \
   '.[$pgid].pogo = $tpogo'
```

---

Testing this with your data:

```
json='{"0000000":{"pogo":"AJHVUYKJBOIHKNNLNM"},"7000000":{"pogo":"PPPVUYKJBOIHKNNLNM"}}'
pgid="0000000"
tpogo="XXXXXXX"

jq --arg pgid "$pgid" --arg tpogo "$tpogo" \
   '.[$pgid].pogo = $tpogo' <<<"$json"
```

...emits as output:

```
{
  "0000000": {
    "pogo": "XXXXXXX"
  },
  "7000000": {
    "pogo": "PPPVUYKJBOIHKNNLNM"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did see that but It did not make much sense to me at the time, but now it does. Also .. is it necessary to line break your command?