# How to pass bash variable as a key to jq?

Tags: bash, shell, jq

Here is the example json

```
{
   "app": "K8s",
   "version": "1.8",
   "date": "2018-10-10"
}
```

In order to get the value of app, I can do this in jq as

```
jq '.app'
```

But what I want is, I want to pass the key to jq as a bash variable, i.e

```
bash_var="app"
jq '."${bash_var}"'
```

I'm getting the output as **null** instead of the value. What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: @BenjaminW/tripleee.: I would have closed it a duplicate, if not for the 2nd part of the question, that involves using the variable as the key. I think that warrants the need for the question to be unique

Comment: We do have existing duplicates covering the key case specifically, though (or at least, covering failures that take place with naive solutions). Let me hunt around...

Comment: ...ahh, what I was thinking of was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562653/invalid-numeric-literal-error-from-jq-trying-to-modify-json-with-variable/52562738#52562738

Comment: So the question is in parts duplicate to [Passing bash variable to jq select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027395/passing-bash-variable-to-jq-select) and [“Invalid numeric literal” error from jq trying to modify JSON with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52562653/5291015), but not completely

Answer (score 32, accepted):

First, you need to port the `bash` variable into `jq`'s context usign the `--arg` flag and access it inside the `[..]`

```
jq --arg keyvar "$bash_var" '.[$keyvar]' json
```

Comment: I do not think you have to port the `bash` variable to `jq`'s context. You can simply achieve the goal by following: `jq ".$bash_var"`

Comment: @JaroslavBezděk: That can easily break when $bash_var contains `"` or any other character interpreted by `jq`.