# Shell Script jq reading a json key with period (.) inside a variable

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have some json data which looks like below:

```
{"spark.master": "local"}
```

I have this stored in a shell variable called `json_data`

```
json_data='{"spark.master": "local"}'
```

and parsing this using the jq shell utility.

As seen above, the key contains a period (.) character. If I try to read it directly using jq, it works fine

```
$ json_data='{"spark.master": "local"}'
$ val=$(echo $json_data | jq .'"spark.master"')
$ echo $val
"local"
```

But if this key is stored in a variable, its not working

```
$ key="spark.master"
$ val=$(echo $json_data | jq .'$key')
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$key 
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$key
jq: 2 compile errors


$ val=$(echo $json_data | jq ."$key")
$ echo $val
null
```

Can someone please help me identify what is going wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732473/how-to-pass-bash-variable-as-a-key-to-jq

Comment: @KamilCuk: Thanks. This worked for me.