# How to get value of numeric object property via jq?

Tags: json, bash, key, jq

I have a json object with numeric keys in an `example.json` file:

```
{
  "1": "foo",
  "2": "bar"
}
```

I want to get its properties by key via `jq`, and I have tried:

```
$ jq ."1" example.json
0.1
```

and

```
jq .["1"] example.json
jq: error (at example.json:4): Cannot index object with number
```

The result should be

```
"foo"
```

though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460453/how-to-use-jq-for-a-query-where-key-is-a-numeric-string

Comment: The following link answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460453/how-to-use-jq-for-a-query-where-key-is-a-numeric-string

Answer (score 3):

The command:

```
jq ."1" example.json
```

doesn't work because the quotes are interpreted by the shell and the first argument that `jq` receives is `.1`. The command above is identical to `jq .1 example.json` and it is not correct as `jq` reports.

You need to enclose the `jq` program in apostrophes to prevent the shell interpret any character in it:

```
jq '."1"' example.json
```

This way, `jq` receives `."1"` as its program and happily interprets it.

You can also put the key name into square brackets (as you have already tried) but it doesn't add any improvement, it's the same program only bloated. And it gives you more reasons to put it into apostrophes to protect it from the shell:

```
jq '.["1"]' example.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes:

```
$ jq '."1"' example.json
"foo"
```